# Does GetECDsaPrivateKey return handle to private key in TPM?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, ecdsa

We are generating certificates that are supposed to have an ECDSA key stored on the TPM.  My understanding is that the GetECDsaPrivateKey extension method will load a handle to the algorithm for the private key in the TPM.  Is this true?  The certs we are testing with keep returning null and I need to know if they are simply being created incorrectly or if the test code is bad.  The MSDN method description isn't very helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it was told to look there.

On Windows, .NET's X509Certificate2 is backed by the Windows certificate APIs. Windows certificates have properties (in addition to their in-certificate attributes), and one of the properties identifies where the private key lives (in effect, the arguments to `CngKey.Open`) -- if the property is missing (and the "I have already opened the private key [here]" property is also missing) then the cert "has no private key" (cert.HasPrivateKey == false).

If your certificate is part of a Windows Certificate Store, and viewing that store via MMC shows the private key icon, then `GetECDsaPrivateKey()` can open it (assuming the key wasn't deleted after the fact, and that it's an ECDsa-capable key).

If you load the certificate from a `.cer` file, or some other means, then the cert doesn't know that there's a private key available, and it never searches for it.  If you know how to find the private key and open it into an ECDsa object (e.g. ECDsaCng) then you can (in-memory) associate them by `X509Certificate2 certWithKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(key);`.  At that point, having been told where the private key lives, the new object's `GetECDsaPrivateKey()` works as expected.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks.  I'll have to try this out.  I was being lazy and just loading the cert from the crt file into the X509Certificate2 object.  I'll open it from the certificate store instead and see if that method works for me.

Answer (score 0):

That GetECDsaPrivateKey only gets the key if it's part of the certificate.  To use a key from the TPM, you need to use the CngKey.Open() method with the name of the key and the storage provider.